# Topology checker - whole polygon highlighted rather than polygon segment

Tags: qgis-2, topology

When I check for overlaps, topology checker is only identifying errors at the polygon level but not the polygon segment where the errors exist (the whole polygon is highlighted in blue).

I believe this may be happening because the nodes aren't snapped together but the overlap is so small (I checked node coordinates between adjacent polygons and there is no difference in at the 4 decimal places shown). I can fix the error manually but it involves pulling each node apart for the entire polygon as I don't know where the overlap actually exists and then snapping all nodes back but this takes a long time to complete.

Is there any way I can automate or semi-automate this snapping process?

Attached image shows the highlight polygon in blue with the error but not the polygon segment that normally is shown in red:

[image: attached image shows the highlight polygon in blue with the error but not the polygon segment that normally is shown in red]

Comment: I don't know if you ever fixed this problem. However, I had the same problem and buffering with a distance of `0` helped in my case.